# Apple XCode on multiple machines (how to take my project with me?)

Tags: xcode, macos

I mainly develop iOS applications on a Mac desktop, but sometimes I travel with a MacBook Air laptop and I often need to continue working on an app while on the road.

Of course, it's possible to just scp the files to my laptop, work on it, then scp it back to the desktop, or use a thumb drive. But I have to believe that thousands of others have a similar need.  Is there a simple way to share the source control and just check in/out while on the road?

What are the best practices for smooth, single-developer track development on multiple devices?

Comment: I'm no expert but git seems to do this well.  You can set up a master repository on your desktop and clone it to your laptop.  When you do a laptop commit, it asks if you want to push to the master.

Comment: Phillip, that actually sounds like the best fit for my needs; can't put this source code on a "cloud" server because of company policy.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this question belongs here, but hey, I ask it myself, so these are my practices. I won't call it "best" practices, just the stuff that I tried over the years:

## Git

Use a git repository. I guess you're already using it, if not, create a repository (in [Bitbucket](http://www.bitbucket.com) you can have private repos for free). Do it even if you use something else to sync your computers.

There are many ways of using git to keep your desktop and laptop synchronised. When it's not easy to perform proper commits (i.e. you're in the middle of a big change and you don't want to just commit everything under a non-sense commit log) you can write a throw away commit using a predetermined message like `** SYNC **`, then push it to your remote.

In your laptop, pull and soft reset to have the changes as they were before committing: `git reset HEAD^`.

When you're back to your desktop, do a hard reset of the last commit `git reset --hard HEAD^` and pull the changes.

**Not the best solution** in my experience: the transition desktop/laptop should be fast and effortless. Thinking about what to commit and how just because you need to change the machine is a pain.

## Resilio Sync

Synchronize several folders between desktop and laptop with Bittorrent Resilio Sync (it's possible to configure it to use only LAN if you're paranoid about security).

It worked for a while, very well, but somehow it broke and I didn't want to investigate the cause because I suspected it'll break again later.

## Dropbox

Synchronize both computers using Dropbox, when I'm lazy. It works fine. If you trust Dropbox anyway.

Same thing with other cloud providers (except iCloud that is painfully slow).

## SSD Card

Work directly in an SSD card. It's fast enough; just make sure you don't write the builds to the card. You need a card reader in both computers, obviously. Not a long term solution.

## Mac Apps

Dedicated mac apps that sync folders between machines. None of them worked flawlessly. Some were too complicated, or unmaintained, or horrible windows ports,  etc. I'd buy a simple one that works and communicates clearly what it does under the hood.

## Rsync

Use `rsync` to keep the project folder synchronised in both computers.

Right now I use the `rsync` solution on top of macOS shared folders (you can use it over SSH if you prefer).

I have a couple of shell scripts per project inside the project folder:

```
project-name->laptop.sh
project-name->desktop.sh
```

Where "laptop" and "desktop" are my machine names. When I need to use the laptop I just mount the shared folder (usually I just need to open the laptop) and run `project-name->laptop.sh`. When I'm back, I'll do the opposite, I run `project-name->desktop.sh`. Simple and easy. You can have each script in the corresponding machine only, to avoid mistakes.

Example:

```
PROJECT_DIR=/Volumes/julian/path/to/project

if [ ! -d $PROJECT_DIR ] ; then
    echo "Mount $PROJECT_DIR first."
    exit 10
fi

if [ ! -x ./sync.sh ] ; then
    echo "Must run from /local/path/project directory"
    exit 11
fi

./sync.sh $PROJECT_DIR project-name $@
```

And `sync.sh` is the same for all projects, something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# sync.sh <project-folder> [-no]
#
SOURCE_DIR=$1 && shift
TARGET_DIR=$1 && shift

function usage {
    echo $0 '<project> [-no]'
}

if [ "$SOURCE_DIR" == "" ] ; then
    echo 'Missing source'
    usage
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$TARGET_DIR" == "" ] ; then
    echo 'Missing target'
    usage
    exit 2
fi

rsync $@ -va --delete         \
      --exclude='*.pyc'       \
      --exclude='*.db'       \
      --exclude='__pycache__' \
      --exclude='.DS_Store'   \
      --exclude='._*'         \
      ${SOURCE_DIR}/ \
      ${TARGET_DIR}/
```

I have used some other solution that I have forgotten already. For me `rsync` is the most easy and stable alternative.

Comment: If OP already isn't already using remote repositories I think is crucial if working with an important project to be used as backup as well as convenient when working among multiple computers.

Answer (score 3):

Use a free BitBucket account, combined with SourceTree. Apart from being able to use this on multiple computers, you also have version control and backup for free.

Comment: Bitbucket and Github are great suggestions; I hadn't even thought of that.  Of course my employer might not like the idea of my putting source code out on the Internet like that.  I was hoping to keep it more private.